# unable to see the profile of paypal sandbox test account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to test payment with PayPal test accounts but something's wrong here...

As you know, PayPal automatically creates the sandbox test accounts by adding "-buyer" or "-facilitator" keyword to the original PayPal account when you register developer's page. 2 sandbox test accounts are automatically generated for me so I clicked 'Profile' of each account to change the password. (below picture)
[image]

But after clicking 'Profile' to revise my information, there's nothing but the only one modal window appears like a picture below and never disappears.
[image]

I'm not able to access to the profile of each sandbox test accounts.. what is wrong with this? It keeps shows me the same message and makes me wait forever even though I created another sandbox test account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed by Paypal already. If the account was creating in the past 3-4 days, maybe you will still see this error. We strongly recommend you deleting old test accounts and re-create new ones.